# selecting 3 couples from 6 couples

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

[image]

Shouldn't the answer be $\binom{6}{3}$ since the order doesn't matter? But the answer is 36 - how can I get this answer?

Comment: If you want to include same-sex couples, the answer is $$\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\frac{1}{2\times 2}$$ since you pick $3$ couples from $12$ people, but, say, $(AB)(CD)(EF)$ is the same as $(EF)(CD)(AB)$.

Comment: The answer in the text is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The answer in the text is wrong.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis  The answer in the text is wrong, which is the reason for the OP's confusion.  She correctly solved the question.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm sorry. I confused myself.